# Polymer simulation

Tags: monte-carlo, polymers, atomistic-simulation

I am absolutely new to Polymer simulation. I am trying to understand the simulation by analyzing source code written by others.

Can anyone tell me what are the differences between the following three source code in terms of their objectives?

1. [Monte-Carlo-simulation-of-polymers](https://github.com/mwb0506/Monte-Carlo-simulation-of-polymers)
2. [PolymerPhysicsSimulation](https://github.com/tianchuliang/PolymerPhysicsSimulation)
3. [Polymer-MonteCarlo](https://github.com/amir-saadat/Polymer-MonteCarlo)

For example, I want to know:

1. if they achieve the same objectives, i.e., polymer growth.
2. if they represent bio-polymers (e.g. proteins) or synthetic polymers.
3. if they are lattice-based or off-lattice simulations.
4. if they represent hard-polymers or soft-polymers.

Comment: To me the question seems broad. You ask a lot of different question about several different programs, none of which are widely used/known based on their last updates and GitHub stats. I think it would better if you chose one of these packages, tried to analyze/run it yourself, and then asked about specific problems you encounter.

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.